# MarkerResolution not shown when invoked with quickassist shortcut

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I'm working on an eclipse plugin where i've created a custom resource marker together with a markerResolution to added quickfixes to XML files. So far everything is working, except that the quickFix only shows in the `Problem` view of eclipse. The quickassist popup which is opend using `Ctrl+1` in the XML file itself does not show the quickfix.

The marker definition can be found [here](https://github.com/pulse00/Symfony-2-Eclipse-Plugin/blob/master/com.dubture.symfony.core/plugin.xml#L130), the markerResolution is [this one](https://github.com/pulse00/Symfony-2-Eclipse-Plugin/blob/master/com.dubture.symfony.ui/plugin.xml#L381).

Is there any additional extension point i need to implement to make the quickFix show up in the shortcut popup?

Answer (score 0):

I think i found the solution. One needs to implement an [editorConfiguration](https://github.com/pulse00/Symfony-2-Eclipse-Plugin/blob/master/com.dubture.symfony.ui/plugin.xml#L394) for the XML editor with a provisionalConfiguration.

In this class you parse the AnnotationModel and check for your marker. If the marker is found, you return an [ICompletionProposal](https://github.com/pulse00/Symfony-2-Eclipse-Plugin/blob/master/com.dubture.symfony.ui/src/com/dubture/symfony/ui/quickassist/QuickAssistProcessor.java#L84)